# Saving High Score in Processing

Tags: processing

For about the past hour I've been wondering how to read from and write to a .txt file in Processing so I can save a high score in my game.

My .txt file looks like this:

```
High Score:
0
```

Currently my code looks like this:

```
void setup() {
  int score;
  String[] saveHighScore = loadStrings("highScore.txt");
  highScore = int(saveHighScore[1]);
}
```

Then lower down the code when the current score becomes greater than the previous high score it does this:

```
highScore = score;
String[] saveHighScore = {"High Score: ", str(highScore)};
saveStrings(dataFile("highScore.txt"), saveHighScore);
```

These pieces of code I have gotten off various forums or the official Processing website and nothing updates. It's a small feature that I would like in my game.

Comment: This won't compile

Comment: Don’t tag processing questions with the Java tag.

Comment: A minimal example that shows the effect would be helpful (for you and others).

Answer (score 1):

The best advice I can give you is to [break your problem down into smaller steps](http://happycoding.io/tutorials/how-to/program) and take those steps on one at a time.

For example, can you create a simple sketch that just tests out saving some data to a file? Check out [the reference](https://processing.org/reference/) for a ton of useful functions. You'll probably want to use the `saveStrings()` function. The reference contains an example:

```
String words = "apple bear cat dog";
String[] list = split(words, ' ');

// Writes the strings to a file, each on a separate line
saveStrings("nouns.txt", list);
```

Get this working perfectly before you move on. Try to understand exactly what this code is doing instead of copy-pasting it and hoping for the best.

After you get that working, then try to load that data. Again, the reference is your best friend. Here's some example code that uses the `loadStrings()` function:

```
String[] lines = loadStrings("list.txt");
println("there are " + lines.length + " lines");
for (int i = 0 ; i < lines.length; i++) {
  println(lines[i]);
}
```

Get this working perfectly before you move on. Try to understand exactly what it's doing.

After you have both of those simpler sketches working by themselves, you can start thinking about putting them together. Again, start simple! Don't try to integrate this into your full game until you understand how it works. Can you create a simpler sketch that loads a single string into memory, and adds to that string when the user types?

Comment: I just tried that example and the saveStrings() function doesn't work

Comment: Wait, my bad, it was saving the text file but outside the data folder